# How to change argument type from str to an object for a cmd.Cmd command

Tags: python

I want to create a **cmd.Cmd** command which accepts an argument to use a consumable item (it's a text base adventure)

```py
import cmd
class Adventure(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = ">"

# Other commands cut out because they are not part of the problem   

    def do_use(self, arg):
        arg.use(pc)
```

Where **arg** will be an object of the **Consumable** class with a **self.use(target)** function already defined before in the code (in the example, the **potion** object)

```py
class Consumable:
    def __init__(self, hpgain):
        self.hpgain = hpgain

    def use(self, target):
        inventory.remove(self)
        target.addhp(self.hpgain)

potion = Consumable(5)
inventory = []
inventory.append(potion)
```

And **pc** is an object of a **Player** class which has a **self.addhp(amount)** function already defined in the code

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp):
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxhp = hp

    def addhp(self, amount):
        self.hp += amount
        if self.hp > self.maxhp:
            self.hp = self.maxhp

pc = Player(20)
```

Both the **potion.use(pc)** and the **pc.addhp(amount)** functions are working in the standard Python shell

When i try to use the **potion** object typing **use potion** in the custom shell the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[Redacted]\Desktop\adventure.py", line 225, in <module>
    Adventure().cmdloop()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\cmd.py", line 138, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\cmd.py", line 217, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "C:\Users\[Redacted]\Desktop\adventure.py", line 199, in do_use
    arg.use(pc)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'use'
```

So it is considering the argument of the function as a string instead of an object. How do i change that?

Comment: You haven't given enough context here. Where is `do_use` being called from and how? Where are the other instances being created and how do they relate to Adventure?

Comment: `inventory` is also somthing that we don't know where it comes from.

Comment: Edited to insert the **inventory** list, even if that's not part of the problem imho, because **potion.use(pc)** works fine. **do_use** is a **cmd.Cmd** function: cmd.Cmd creates a custom shell in which you put command lines such as **help**, defining them as functions named **do_foo** where **foo** is the line to type in the custom shell to execute the function. You must first import cmd tho, which i've done in my code but forgot to transcribe here :/ .

Comment: Well, having the inventory as a module variable looks like a horrible idea (scope issues). So someone will type `use potion` and `do_use` gets called with `"potion"` as `arg`. Right? And now you want to convert `"potion"` into `potion`.

Comment: Yes they are treated as command line arguments. I believe it may be possible to perform a lookup based on the string name, however this is typically frowned upon. Try `globals()[arg].use(pc)`

Comment: That will also have a lot of scope issues.

Comment: Exactly, i want for the command to consider the arg as an object instead of a string with the same name. As you said, it must look to **potion**, not **"potion"**

Comment: One question, will the inventory have some kind of limit? Maybe it cna only hold a certain amount of items or maybe only a certain amount of types or maybe each item has a weight and it can only handle a certain total weight?

Comment: I think @Adirio just wants to help you with your game lol! There are some ways to convert command line arguments into objects but they are pretty convoluted. My approach is the simplest and most straightforward even with the obvious flaws!

Comment: @ Adirio i'm focusing on one feature at a time, but i plan it to have no limits for now. After all, it's my first program in python (and at all, if we don't count training ones).
@TheLazyScripter that should be used in place of **arg.use(pc)**, right? I'll try and let you know.

Comment: yes as shown in my answer below!

Comment: The thing is that you should probably create a class for the inventory later, so we can do it now and make it work like a dictionary so that we can access each items by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cmd module parses each arg as a command line argument, in this case it's a string. In Python there are several ways to look up `objects` currently loaded into memory by name. `globals` is one of them. If the object you are trying to locate happens to be declared i.e(`x=5`) in another module then we can use `getattr(module_name, var_name)` instead!

```
class Adventure(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = ">"

# Other commands cut out because they are not part of the problem   

    def do_use(self, arg):
        globals()[arg].use(pc) #if potion is declared in the current module
        #getattr(module_where_it_is_declared, arg).use(pc) #if potion is declared in another module
```

Let me know if this worked!

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you!
Now: just a small question: if i wanted to make an if clause to check if the arg is in the Consumable class and in the inventory, should i write:
if globals()[arg] in inventory and isinstance(globals()[arg], Consumable) ?

Comment: Yep, the globals lookup returns the original instance of the obj so it will eval to equal when compared to it's self!

Comment: Update: apparently, if you input 'use thing' and 'thing' is not an object at all it gives me an error. 'if globals()[arg] in inventory and isinstance(globals()[arg], Consumable):
KeyError: 'thing''
How can i write the command to prevent this and simply write "This is not a consumable item"? @TheLazyScripter

Comment: @Djarrah I would encase it in a `try/catch` and check for the specific exception, in this case it would be a `KeyError`. We could also check for any exception, or multiple exceptions. `try: my_code_to_try` `except KeyError: print("Whatever you want"`

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Inventory` class like the following:

```py
from cmd import Cmd
from collections import Counter


class Inventory(Counter):
    """
    We can extend the Inventory class later. For now it will work as a Counter
    so that we can keep track of the number of each item it has
    """


class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp):
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.inventory = Inventory()

    def has(self, item_name):
        # Check that there is a positive amount of that item
        return item_name in self.inventory and self.inventory[item_name] > 0

    def use(self, item_name, item):
        # We are passing both the item_name and the item as we want to use it
        # We could also use the item itself as the key for the Inventory instead
        # of the item name, so that we do not need both (method has would also
        # need an update in that case)

        # Check if it is consumable to reduce the amount by one
        if isinstance(item, Consumable):
            self.inventory[item_name] -= 1

        # Use the item passing the player as it will have to access its addhp method
        item.use(self)

    def addhp(self, amount):
        self.hp += amount
        if self.hp > self.maxhp:
            self.hp = self.maxhp


class Consumable:  # You should probably add a base class Item later
    def use(self, player):
        pass  # This will be overwritten by other classes


class Potion(Consumable):
    """
    The Potion class allows to define different sizes of pots that will heal
    the player the specified amount.
    """
    def __init__(self, hp):
        """Define the amount of hp that a potion heals."""
        self.hp = hp

    def use(self, player):
        """Heal the player by the specified amount."""
        player.addhp(self.hp)


class Adventure(Cmd):
    prompt = ">"

    # This is just a map of item names to their current objects
    items = {
        "small potion": Potion(2),
        "potion": Potion(5),
        "big potion": Potion(10),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call parent class constructor IMPORTANT!
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Now we handle our own instance variables
        self.player = Player(20)

    def do_use(self, item_name):
        # Check before using
        if self.player.has(item_name):
            self.player.use(item_name, self.items[item_name])
```

The `do_use` method is not thread-safe, so if you add different threads in any point remember that you should add use a lock somewhere.

Comment: Being able to have multiple instances of the same objects is interesting, i'll edit the code later and let you know if this is better.
Ps: **from cmd import Cmd** doesn't seem to work

Comment: `from cmd import Cmd` works but you have to use `Cmd` not `cmd.Cmd`